# Is it possible with SQLAlchemy to create a single class that then goes into parent and child tables?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, common-table-expression

Is it possible with SQLAlchemy to create a single class that then goes into different tables? If there weren't specific columns that need to go in each table, I would just create a trigger so that an employee is created in the employee table instead when a manager/engineer is created, like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION new_employee()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $new_employee$
   DECLARE 
 newid text;
   role text;
 thisdate date;
   BEGIN
   SELECT CURRENT_DATE INTO thisdate;
      role := TG_TABLE_NAME::regclass::text;
      EXECUTE format($$INSERT INTO employee (name,type,date_added) VALUES ($1.name,%L,%L) RETURNING id $$, role,thisdate) INTO newid using NEW;
      NEW.id := newid;
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$new_employee$
```

But that doesn't work if there are fields I need to input data on for both tables.
Based on examples in the documentation, I have used SQLAlchemy to make some tables with joined inheritence:

```
class Company(Base):
  __tablename__ = "company"
  id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
  name: Mapped[str]
  managers: Mapped[List[Manager]] = relationship(back_populates="company")


Company.__table__
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


class Employee(Base):
  __tablename__ = "employee"
  id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
  name: Mapped[str]
  type: Mapped[str]
  social: Mapped[int]
  test: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
  date_added: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(nullable=True)

  __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_identity": "employee",
    "polymorphic_on": "type",
  }

class Manager(Employee):
  __tablename__ = "manager"
  id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("employee.id"), primary_key=True)
  name: Mapped[str]
  CheckConstraint("name == employee.name", name="check1")
  branch: Mapped[str]

  company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id"))
  company: Mapped[Company] = relationship(back_populates="managers")

  __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_identity": "manager",
  }


class Engineer(Employee):
  __tablename__ = "engineer"
  id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("employee.id"), primary_key=True)
  name: Mapped[str]
  specialty: Mapped[str]

  company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id"))
  company: Mapped[Company] = relationship(back_populates="engineers")

  __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_identity": "engineer",
  }

  
Engineer.__table__
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I figured out how to write an SQL statement that does what I want for a single insert, but can I use the SQLAlchemy (and hopefully ORM) to generate (or at least fill the variables into) a statement like the following?

```
WITH insert_child AS (
    INSERT INTO employee (name,type,social) VALUES
    ('Merv', 'manager',123456789)
    RETURNING id,name
)
INSERT INTO manager
SELECT 
    /* parent data */
    id,name,'main',
FROM insert_child;
```

edit: I think this might be the solution, I will report back after I've tried a few things: [How can I establish a database relationship that allows different types of users to register in SqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870344/how-can-i-establish-a-database-relationship-that-allows-different-types-of-users?rq=2)

edit2: That was solution. It wasn't obvious from the title what that thread was, I almost didn't even click on it.